# Turn HTML table into array with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have the following table:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd first-child">
        <td class="first-child account_name">Label 1</td>
        <td class="last-child balance">Amount 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <td class="first-child account_name">Label 2</td>
        <td class="last-child balance">Amount 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td class="first-child account_name">Label 3</td>
        <td class="last-child balance">Amount 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <td class="first-child account_name">Label 4</td>
        <td class="last-child balance">Amount 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td class="first-child account_name">Label 5</td>
        <td class="last-child balance">Amount 5</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to turn it into an array using javascript, so that "Label 1" is the key for value "Amount 1," "Label 2" is the key for value "Amount 2," etc.

How might I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I tried to use this post as a reference, to no avail: http://www.fourfront.us/blog/store-html-table-data-to-javascript-array

Comment: It just returns [object, Object] 6 times

Comment: Also, you don't need the even/odd classes, css3 supports :odd and :even selectors.

Comment: The table is actually pulled from another, outdated site, and I'm trying to get the data into an analyzable form. Believe me, I wish I could change it

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is simply loop over the nodes.

```js
var c = document.querySelectorAll('#tgt td');
var d = {};
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i += 2) {
  d[c[i].innerHTML] = c[i + 1].innerHTML;
}
console.log(d);
```

```html
<table id="tgt">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd first-child">
      <td class="first-child account_name">Label 1</td>
      <td class="last-child balance">Amount 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="first-child account_name">Label 2</td>
      <td class="last-child balance">Amount 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="first-child account_name">Label 3</td>
      <td class="last-child balance">Amount 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="first-child account_name">Label 4</td>
      <td class="last-child balance">Amount 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="first-child account_name">Label 5</td>
      <td class="last-child balance">Amount 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try simulate key/value pairs using following javascript:

```
var trElements = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var keyValue = [];

for(var i = 0; i < trElements.length; i++)
{
    var tdElements = trElements[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    keyValue.push({"key":tdElements[0].innerHTML,"value":tdElements[1].innerHTML});
}
```

With following html:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Key1</td>
            <td>Value1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Key2</td>
            <td>Value2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

That way you can get the value of your key or value by either choosing keyValue[i].key or keyValue[i].value. I think it's the simplest way. I don't think js supports key-value pairs by default.